# Tengo un error con [(ngModel)] en una aplicacion de ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic2

Tengo un error y no se que es lo que se esta haciendo mal
mi código es el siguiente:

**Html**

```
<ion-col col-12 class="informacion flex" *ngFor=" let edad of edades; let i=index ">
    <ion-input class="" [(ngModel)]="edad" type="text" placeholder="Ej: (7-12) Infantil, Etc..." ></ion-input>
    <button class="papelera" ion-button color="rojoTomato" clear icon-only (click)="eliminarEdad(i)">
        <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

**ts**

```
edades = [''];
```

**Error**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot assign to a reference or
>   variable! Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

**Otros Ejemplos que si funcionan:**

**Html**

```
<ion-col col-12 class="flex" *ngFor=" let valor of valores; let i=index ">
    <ion-input class="" [(ngModel)]="valor[0]" type="text" placeholder="Ej: Infantil" ></ion-input>
    <ion-input class="" [(ngModel)]="valor[1]" type="text" placeholder=" $20.000 COP." ></ion-input>
    <button ion-button class="papelera" color="rojoTomatoColsport" clear icon-only (click)="eliminarValor(i)">
        <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline" ></ion-icon>
    </button>
</ion-col>
```

**ts**

```
valores= [['','']];
```

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta (cual te soluciona el error) pero al no saber más en detalle de tus intenciones no te puedo dar otras opciones para conseguir lo que realmente necesitas. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error esta diciendo que no puedes asignar a `[(ngModel)]` una variable/referencia creada localmente para el valor del input dinámicamente.

Una solución sería referir al objeto `edades` para evitar el fallo:

```
[(ngModel)]="edades[i]"
```

Pero pierdes el foco `(focus)` del input, porque estás repitiendo sobre una matriz y estás cambiando los elementos de la matriz.

Comment: Correcto, esa era la solución que tenia, no me gusta que el usuario pierda el foco por cada letra que oprima, como puedo evitar eso?
lo hago como una matriz por que necesito que darle la opción al usuario de crear nuevos campos, me parece curioso que en el formulario manejo muchos campos que son matriz de dos dimensiones y esas funcionan a la perfección, dejo el ejemplo en la pregunta.